# How do I reuse code from another file in a new stand-alone generic class?

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, stack

I am trying to create a new generic class to implement stack operations "Stack.java", while reusing code from another file "LinkedList.java" that includes linked list operations such as remove first node. This linked list file includes only the integer type and is non-generic. How do I get this "Stack.java" started? I am not allowed to use inheritance.

This is how I've tried starting the generic class and connecting to the other file, but I keep getting errors.

public class Stack
{

```
  private LinkedList stack = new LinkedList();
```

Comment: Please follow the [contribution guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to ask a good question.

Comment: "*to the other file*" - **what other file?** "*getting errors*" - **what errors?**